# Schedule a single button press very easily?

Tags: windows, macros

I am looking for a (macro) program for windows (10) that allows me to

- move the mouse around so the pc doesn't automatically go to sleep.
- then press the enter-key (or better: a series of keys) at a specific point in time.

I need the program to be extremely simple and reliable, and without scripting and so forth.

Everything I've found online is very complex.

Comment: Please provide a little bit for context-info about the "then press the enter-key (or better: a series of keys) at a specific point in time." what defines that point in time?

Answer (score 1):

I know you said no scripting but your best option, I believe is AutoHotKey.

You will need the MoveMouse function

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseMove.htm

The Send function

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm

The Random Function and SetTimer function

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Random.htm
https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm

Really quick your script could look like this (not tested)

```
#Persistent ; keep the script open after first execution

PressEnter(times) ; function to press enter key
{
 Loop, %times% ; Loop the number of times variable
  {
   Send {Enter} ; Send enter key
   Sleep, 100 ; Sleep for 100 ms for security
  }
}

SetTimer, MoveMouse, 600000; Every 10 mins in ms

MoveMouse: ; what to do every 10 mins
Random, x, 1, 1920 ; Get a random number between 1 and 1920 asuming res. is full HD
Random, y, 1, 1080 ; Get a random number between 1 and 1080
Random, EnterKeyTimes, 1, 10 ; Get random number for Enter key presses
MouseMove, x, y ; Move Mouse to these random numbers
PressEnter(EnterKeyTimes) ; Call the function with the EnterKeyTimes variable
```

This code has not been tested but it probably works or needs a few changes. Give it a go

Of course, if you don't want random numbers but you want certain x,y coordinates and a specific number of Enter key presses, create the variables and assign values to them like this:

```
x = 1000  ; Set x to 1000 
y = 1000  ; Set y to 1000
EnterKeyTimes = 3 ; Enter key to be pressed 3 times
```